# group separator with savetrees

Tags: siunitx, savetrees

I am trying to have a group separator between 3-digits groups. However the package savetrees removes the group separator. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}

\begin{document}
\num{100000}
\end{document}
```

How can I have an output like this: "100 000" without removing the savetrees package? Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `savetrees` package sets `\thinmuskip` to `0.0mu plus 3.0mu` rather than the standard `\3.0mu`. The easiest solution is to reverse that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}
\AtBeginDocument{\thinmuskip = 3mu}
\begin{document}
\num{100000}
\end{document}
```

but that will apply to all uses of the value. We might therefore hard-code the skip

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[subtle]{savetrees}
\sisetup{group-separator = \ensuremath{\mkern 3.0mu\relax}}
\begin{document}
\num{100000}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I ended up using the first option as it didn't change the page-count of my document.